# Can't use random.choice() function on a list?

Tags: python, random

So I'm trying to make a random string generator, of four characters which goes as a consonant, a vowel, a consonant, and then a vowel. I don't want any consonants to be used more than once. etc. **kajo** or **qyzu**. However, I'm having trouble with the `random.choice()` method which is not expected. When I run the program, I get the below error:

```
  File "C:\User\Documents\Coding\Python\string_generator.py", line 6, in <module>
    i = random.choice(consonants)
  File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 346, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code is below:

```
import random

vowels = 'aeiouy'
consonants = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','m','n','p','q','q','r','s','t','v','v','v','v','w','x','x','x','x','z','z','z','z']
for num in range(20):
    i = random.choice(consonants)
    word = i
    for x in consonants:
        if x == i:
            consonants.remove(x)
    word += random.choice(vowels)
    i = random.choice(consonants)
    word += i
    for x in consonants:
        if x == i:
            consonants.remove(x)
    word += random.choice(vowels)
```

Comment: it's because your list is empty.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how so? I defined it as consonants = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','m','n','p','q','q','r','s','t','v','v','v','v','w','x','x','x','x','z','z','z','z']

Comment: you are removing from that list... what happens if you *remove everything*... which it what happens when you runt his code always, because there are 20 unique consonants in your list, and you remove those randomly until your list is empty

Comment: Do you know what does this do - ```consonants.remove(x)``` ?

Comment: @Ram it should remove ```x``` if it is equal to ```i```

Comment: @qwerteee123 Yes. If you remove the values repeatedly, you will be left with an empty array and that is why the error. Also any reason for having duplicates in ```consonants``` list ?

Comment: @Ram thanks, fixed it now. The duplicates are there to have some characters more likely to come up.

Answer (score 1):

As juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, the list is empty on one of the calls to `random.choice(consonants)` in your `for` loop. You can see this by adding `print(consonants)` as the first line within the loop:

Output:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z']
['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'z', 'z']
['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'r', 's', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'z']
['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'r', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'z']
['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'r', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'x', 'z']
['c', 'f', 'g', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'r', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'x', 'z']
['c', 'f', 'g', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z']
['c', 'f', 'g', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'z']
['c', 'f', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'v', 'w', 'z']
['c', 'f', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'v']
['c', 'f', 'k', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'v']
['c', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'v']
['n', 'p', 'q', 'q']
['p', 'q']
[] <--- Causes the error
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it by defining ```consonants``` in the ```for num in range(20)``` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lot of **for** in your code.

What's string you need to expected at the end?

If you need a string long 20 chars, with unique consonant taken from your array, you need write like this:

```
import random

word = "";
vowels = 'aeiouy'
consonants =['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','m','n','p','q','q','r','s','t','v','v','v','v','w','x','x','x','x','z','z','z','z']
for num in range(20):
    i = random.choice(consonants)
    consonants.remove(i)
    word += random.choice(vowels)
    word += i

print (word)
```

In this case the random string is composed like this pattern: (vowel+consonant)*20

**Output:**

```
utivecojyvuluzavomuxydimisokeziwanohubyx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need 20 times a random of 4 characters with this pattern: consonant+vowel+consonant+vowel, this is the solution:

```
import random

vowels = 'aeiouy'
consonants =['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','m','n','p','q','q','r','s','t','v','v','v','v','w','x','x','x','x','z','z','z','z']
for num in range(20):
    consonantsCopy = consonants.copy()
    firstConsonant = random.choice(consonantsCopy)
    consonantsCopy.remove(firstConsonant)
    secondConsonant = random.choice(consonantsCopy)
    consonantsCopy.remove(secondConsonant)

    tempString = firstConsonant + random.choice(vowels) + secondConsonant + random.choice(vowels)
    print(tempString)
```

**Output:**

```
sufa
quzu
zela
bixo
beju
mafy
vybe
zumo
kozo
```